# Unix: how does cp work for files larger than available RAM?

Tags: unix, filesystems, operating-systems

Does it copy the file in batches, or does it stream the file through memory, reading and writing simultaneously?

Comment: The same way it does for files smaller than available RAM. Processes don't normally concern themselves with the availability or size of physical memory.

Answer (score 1):

Reading and writing simultaneously usually means that a fixed size is read (let's say `1024kb`) and then written immediately. It's useless to read and write `1b` at a time.

Basically it streams the file, but in chunks.